# Attempting to change two values in one column based on the values in another column

Tags: r

I'm attempting to change the 'T' values in the Position column to 'LT' or 'RT' and the 'G' values to 'LG' or 'RG' based on the value in the Y column. For example, whichever of the two 'T' values have the higher Y value between the two should be 'LT' and whichever has the lower should be 'RT'. The same applies for the 'G' Position.

Here is an example data frame:

```
tracking_data <- data.frame(
  GameId = c("2017090700", "2017090700", "2017090700", "2017090700", "2017090700", "2017090700"),
  PlayId = c("20170907000118", "20170907000118", "20170907000118", "20170907000118", "20170907000118", "20170907000118"),
  Y = c(20.92333, 28.21333, 23.84333, 22.80333, 21.45333, 24.86333),
  Position = c("T", "T", "QB", "RB", "G", "G")
)
```

Here is what I would like:

```
tracking_data <- data.frame(
  GameId = c("2017090700", "2017090700", "2017090700", "2017090700", "2017090700", "2017090700"),
  PlayId = c("20170907000118", "20170907000118", "20170907000118", "20170907000118", "20170907000118", "20170907000118"),
  Y = c(20.92333, 28.21333, 23.84333, 22.80333, 21.45333, 24.86333),
  Position = c("RT", "LT", "QB", "RB", "RG", "LG")
)
```

How would I go about doing this? This is just one example and there are thousands of other rows in this dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will generalize to your real data problem, but if you group by `GameID`, `PlayID` and `Position`, then arrange them in increasing order of `Y` by group, you should be able to just paste R and L onto the values G and T and get the right answers.

```r
library(dplyr)
tracking_data <- data.frame(
  GameId = c("2017090700", "2017090700", "2017090700", "2017090700", "2017090700", "2017090700"),
  PlayId = c("20170907000118", "20170907000118", "20170907000118", "20170907000118", "20170907000118", "20170907000118"),
  Y = c(20.92333, 28.21333, 23.84333, 22.80333, 21.45333, 24.86333),
  Position = c("T", "T", "QB", "RB", "G", "G")
)
  
tracking_data %>% 
  group_by(GameId, PlayId, Position) %>% 
  arrange(Y, .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Position = ifelse(Position %in%  c("G", "T"), paste0(c("R", "L"), Position), Position))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Groups:   GameId, PlayId, Position [6]
#>   GameId     PlayId             Y Position
#>   <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1 2017090700 20170907000118  21.5 RG      
#> 2 2017090700 20170907000118  24.9 LG      
#> 3 2017090700 20170907000118  23.8 QB      
#> 4 2017090700 20170907000118  22.8 RB      
#> 5 2017090700 20170907000118  20.9 RT      
#> 6 2017090700 20170907000118  28.2 LT
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Just sort them and use a vectorized replacement with cycling

```
key <- with(tracking_data, paste(GameId, PlayId, Position, Y))
tracking_data <- tracking_data[order(key), ]
tracking_data[tracking_data$Position == 'T', 'Position'] <- c('RT', 'LT')
tracking_data[tracking_data$Position == 'G', 'Position'] <- c('RG', 'LG')
```